# Исчезает данные из console.log

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, вёрстка

Создаю ивент на кнопке, что по нажатию она будет считывать данные из инпутов и выносить их в консоль. Но на деле данные появляются в консоле и тут же пропадают. Заметил что адрес ссылки меняет (перезагружается страница с новым адресом). Как можно такое пофиксить?

```js
let btnRegister = document.querySelector('.submit-button');

const sendDataHandler = () => {
  let elemsInputEmail = document.querySelector('input[type=email]').value;
  let elemsInputName = document.querySelector('input[type=text]').value;
  let elemsInputPass = document.querySelector('input[type=password]').value;
  let res = [elemsInputEmail, elemsInputName, elemsInputPass];
  console.log(res);
};

btnRegister.addEventListener('click', sendDataHandler);
```

```html
  <body>
    <main class="page">
      <form class="login-form">
        <h1 class="form-title">Create user</h1>
        <div class="form-control">
          <label class="form-label" for="email">Email</label>
          <input
            class="form-input"
            type="email"
            id="email"
            name="email"
            placeholder="mail@example.com"
            required
          />
        </div>
        <div class="form-control">
          <label class="form-label" for="email">User name</label>
          <input class="form-input" type="text" name="name" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form-control">
          <label class="form-label" for="password">Password</label>
          <input class="form-input" type="password" name="password" required />
        </div>
        <button class="submit-button" type="submit">Register</button>
      </form>
    </main>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема тут:

```
 <button class="submit-button" type="submit">Register</button>
```

Вы либо поставьте кнопке тип `button`, либо в методе делайте `e.preventDefault()`.

А в целом, раз вы всё равно на js все значения из полей собираете, то зачем вам вообще `form`  и кнопка `submit`?

Comment: Кнопка будет собирать все данные с инпутов, добавлять эти данные в объект и отправлять на сервер

Comment: Кнопка этого делать не будет, это будет делать код в обработчике.....сам тег form зачем? а в качестве кнопки сойдёт тип button, а не submit

Comment: Ну я и имел ввиду, что обработчик кнопки будет делать то, что описал выше. А form и тип кнопки submit указан по заданию, html разметку вообще нельзя менять.

Comment: понятно. тогда `e.preventDefault()`  спасёт. Т.е. `const sendDataHandler = (e) => { e.preventDefault();   ...........`